# How can i create .exe file from github repository?

Tags: python, github

this is the repository in question: https://github.com/LeagueOfPoro/CapsuleFarmerEvolved, I downloaded the zip source code at this link https://github.com/LeagueOfPoro/CapsuleFarmerEvolved/releases, I edited the 'bestStream.txt' file in the 'config' folder, now I would like to create a .exe file (like the one in the release) with my modified file, how can I create it?

Comment: Have you read the installation instructions on GitHub? There is a section on creating a compiled version.

Answer (score 0):

There are pretty good instructions available on how to compile the application. I recommend to take a look:
https://github.com/LeagueOfPoro/CapsuleFarmerEvolved/wiki/Advanced-Installation-for-Windows

**Running from source code**

---

1. Download and extract the latest source code available from the [Releases](https://github.com/LeagueOfPoro/CapsuleFarmerEvolved/releases/) tab or via git clone https://github.com/LeagueOfPoro/CapsuleFarmerEvolved.git
2. Generate the config files as required by the application - see [Configuration](https://github.com/LeagueOfPoro/CapsuleFarmerEvolved/wiki/Configuration) for details.
3. Run `pipenv install` to install the required dependencies.
4. Run `pipenv run python ./src/main.py` to start the application.

**Compiling the application**

---

If the application is running from the source code, you can also compile it into a single executable file using pyinstaller.

1. Run `pipenv install` to install the required dependencies.
2. If you have not already, generate the config files as required by the application - see [Configuration](https://github.com/LeagueOfPoro/CapsuleFarmerEvolved/wiki/Configuration) for details.
3. Open a terminal in the root directory of the project (you should see `src` and `config` directories if you type `dir`).
4. Run `setup/windows.bat` (CMD/PowerShell compatible).
5. The compiled executable will be in the `build` directory. You can quickly start it with `./build/CapsuleFarmerEvolved.exe`

Comment: Suggestion - Please edit your answer and put a summary of instructions here.  Otherwise, your answer is in danger of being deleted.